# is there any way connect to ssh in php netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I want to connect remote server via netbeans, I know netbeans support Ftp and SFTP but in server I want to connect to it there is not any ftp server.
I am using windows 7
Is there any way to connect it with ssh?

I try below with host name `sftp://myhostname.com` but return me error in test connection

[image]

Comment: SFTP *is* SSH (SFTP = SSH File Transfer Protocol) in that they use the same connecting port (port 22). Try establishing a SFTP connection to your server using your SSH login credentials.

Comment: I test sftp://serveraddress.com Ip: 54345 but it return me ,the server not support sftp !!! , I know the server customized ,changed ssh default port, there is no ftp  server and ....

Comment: can you connect to the server via SSH through putty? if so, what configuration do you send through putty?

Comment: yes,I can connect it with putty and winscp,

Comment: Ok, how do you connect to it via PuTTY? (what server do you put in, what username do you provide, etc etc.). Reply with "fake" information if this server can be accessed via the internet and not just a local network.

Comment: It is not local, I connect to it with root user and password, but really it is not support ftp and sftp, only ssh

Comment: "SFTP clients are programs that use SSH to access, manage, and transfer files." If you have SSH, you can use SFTP. SFTP provides a way to add/remove files via the SSH protocol. Use username: root and password: whateverPasswordItIs to connect with SFTP. It's the same thing!

Comment: look at the question again, I update it and take screenshot of sftp connetctin